# Given a sorted linked list and value to insert, write a function to insert the value in sorted way

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

The code below executes but sometimes it doesn't add at some sorted positions...

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH3cg.png) shows the given linked list and list after inserting the new element.

Can someone help me out with this problem?

```
void insert()
{
    p=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    printf("\nEnter data to add : ");
    scanf("%d",&p->data);
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=p;
        p->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        q=start;
        if(q->data > p->data)
        {
            p->next=start;
            start=p;            
        }
        else
        {
            while(p->data > q->data && q->next!=NULL)
            {
                r=q;
                q=q->next;
            }
                q->next=p;
                p->next=NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't post images of the text; post actual text instead.

Comment: `void insert()` refers to a global variable named `start`. Post your code with the `main()`, the `start` variable, and the definition of `NODE`. It will be easier to help you out with your homework

Comment: You wrote "*sometimes* it doesn't add at some sorted positions". This is not clear enough. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Either hard-code the data or provide the corresponding input for a case that reproduces the problem. Show the expected result and the actual result and if necessary explain what's wrong.

Comment: Also, you're implementing this example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/ Why don't you look at their solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is you are either inserting `NODE` at the end of your list, or inserting node in some specific point and deletes rest of the nodes irrespective of their values.

changed the `else` part (when current node data is greater than root node data) like following:

```
 while(p->data > q->data && q->next!=NULL)
 {
     r=q;
     q=q->next;
 }
   
 // r- is the just previous node of the place where new node needs to be inserted.

if(q->next == NULL)
{
    q->next = p; 

   /* this block is the end position of linked list in other words no place found
      where we can insert a node, for example if your list is 1->5->7->11 and
      you want to insert 15, then you need to insert node at the end */
}
else
{
    r->next = p;
    p->next = q;
   /* this is interesting part, r - is the node after which we want to insert new node. 

      so, r->next = p -- actually holds new node after r which p,
      and p->next = q -- holds remaining nodes of linked list.
      
      for example, think, initially your list was:
      3->6->9->11->15 and you want to insert 8, in this case

      r (3, 6) -> next = p (8);
      p (8) -> next = q (9, 11, 15);
      so finally we will get: 3->6->8->9->11->15
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is just a small change in assigning the values in the else part. You used `r` in the loop but never used it afterwards. Here is the corrected code with change in just the while loop condition and assigning after that.

```
void insert()
{
    p=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    printf("\nEnter data to add : ");
    scanf("%d",&p->data);
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=p;
        p->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        q=start;
        if(q->data > p->data)
        {
            p->next=start;
            start=p;
        }
        else
        {   
            while(q!=NULL && p->data >= q->data)
            {
                r=q;
                q=q->next;
            }
            r->next=p;
            p->next=q;
        }
    }
}
```